# Dot Net Nuke 9 Create Site Template

Tags: dotnetnuke

How do I create a site template in Dot Net Nuke 9.x?

I've been googling and pouring over the docs but I'm not seeing it.
I want to be able to create a site and export it as a Site Template.  I see the export option for a site but the format for a site template(for the two default templates that come with DNN) is different.

The default site templates that come with DNN in the ..\Portals_default directory are files with the .template extension.  And opening one starts with a node

```
<portal version="5.0">
```

I would like to be able to give our DNN Admin users a default template to start new sites with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DNN 9 go to

```
Manage > Sites
```

Then hover your mouse over the Site Name and URL. You will see 3 icons. Click on the last one. There is the page you need.

[image]

The template page

[image]

Note: For DNN 8 and lower it is on `Host > Site-Management`. There is a button there named "Export Site Template".

Comment: Ok I did see those buttons trouble is the only one that works is the "eye" which gives me a new view and the "trash" delete site.  But both the "gear" and "template" icons don't do anything

Comment: I test stuff with a basic installation of DNN 9. There it works when logged in as a Host. Are there perhaps javascript errors? If there are try the default skin.

Comment: I'll check the JS errors good point.  It is just a base install of DNN 9